# Incremental Month in Histogram

Tags: date, powerbi, histogram

I have a table with 3 columns: Name, StartDate, EndDate
I need to increment 1 for each month between the two dates

And the histogram must be with moth-Year in X and number of Name in Y

Could explain to me how to do that, please?

Thank you for your support.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhgQL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV5Ee.png)

Comment: Increment what? Update your question with clearer detail and ask.

Comment: Increment number of item on each month

Comment: For example if i have 5 items in my list and 3 of them have start date and end date between January 24 and April 24... January will have 3 / February have 3 / March have 3 etc

Comment: And in May 24 will be 0 if no item have the period

Comment: Any support please ?

Comment: Update your question with more detail/clarity. Include a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/), or add an image or something to help us visualize what you are asking.

Comment: I putted some image for details - Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

**Data table**
Named `YourTable`:

| ITEM | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2025-12-31 |
| Item 2 | 2021-05-01 | 2023-04-30 |
| Item 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| Item 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2024-12-31 |
| Item 5 | 2021-01-01 | 2028-12-31 |

**Date table**
You will need a Date or Calendar table for your model. Here is an example of one. Create a new Calculated Table with:

```
DimDate = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "MonthNum", MONTH([Date]),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Year-Month", FORMAT([Date], "yy-MM"),
    "Month-Year", FORMAT([Date], "MM-yy")
  )
```

Once created, click in turn on each of these columns and sort by...

- `Month` Sort by column `MonthNum`
- `Month-Year` Sort by column `Year-Month`

**Measure**
Create a new Measure with:

```
Item count = 
  var minD = MIN(DimDate[Date])
  var maxD = MAX(DimDate[Date])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS(YourTable),
      REMOVEFILTERS(DimDate),
      YourTable[END DATE] >= minD && YourTable[START DATE] <= maxD
    )
```

**Chart**
Use the `Clustered column chart`, with `DimDate[Month-Year]` for the X-axis, and `[Item Count]` for the Y-axis. In the chart properties, under Columns > Layout, adjust the `Space between categories`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - But I have an error message when I try to apply the modifications : Token Identifier expected.

Comment: All the above is in DAX not PowerQuery. Share a screen grab of the error message in situation.

Comment: I putted the screenshot in an answer

Comment: Strange, it is giving you a PowerQuery error while you are showing a DAX expression. Suggest you revert (undo) changes, check there are no more errors or **pending changes**. Then try again to add a Calculated Table in DAX. Share a link to the PBIX if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... It was an artefact when I started to configure it with PowerQuery.

Comment: How did this go? Resolved? Please help mark answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (check mark below the voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the error message from my PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5zJy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).